# How would I go about calculating the window toolbar area height?

Tags: javascript

[image]

So I'm trying to get the height of the top toolbar area as shown in the image. I'm aware of `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` but that also includes the bottom status bar area, giving me an innacurate number.

How would I go about calculating just the top section height?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean bottom status bar?

Comment: The bottom border edge. Those pixels get included in the height which I don't need.

Comment: Why would you need to know this? In my opinion this is user specific data, you shouldn't be able to access this.

Comment: @010011100101 you mean the white line which is barely 1 pixel?

Comment: I'm using the screen capture api to capture a tab window and cropping a certain area to capture. I have it working in Chrome, but in firefox, the captured area includes the top toolbar, unlike Chrome which just includes the viewport. So I need the height of the toolbar so I know how much space to crop out from the top of the video capture.

Comment: Your original question says "bottom status bar area", but then you said "top toolbar", I don't know which area you are talking about.

Comment: The top toolbar area is shown in the screenshot with the red line. The formula in the question gives you the height of that area in the red line, and the area below the viewport. I only need the height of the red line area as stated in the question.

Comment: Your formula is equal with the verticle red line of your screenshot, it doesn't contain anything else, did you mean horizontal red line?

Comment: My firefox `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` = 113, it's exactly the verticle red line height.

Comment: 113 including tab bar height, search bar height and the bookmark bar height

Comment: Strange, I did the same and came out with 120. I did just figure out a solution though that gave me 114 which is the actual height I measured. I'll post my answer and findings in a bit. I'm currently on mobile.

Comment: My system is latest mac, maybe it's OS related.

Comment: You said you have 120 and 114 result, but there is no 6px related bar height, did you run the command while horizontal scroll bar appeared?

Comment: @xyz I've posted my answer. Just curious to see if you get the same result on your mac with both methods. Thanks. Also, to answer your question, no scrollbar was present.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a hacky way to do it. You have to trigger a pointerEvent and get the screenY and clientY of the mouse position. Subtract the clientY position from the screenY position. This will then give you the top viewport screenY position. Then you subtract the window.screenY from the top viewport screenY position and this will give you the tab\toolbar\bookmark height.

**When testing the code snippet, use the JSFiddle link below to run it in a full view. Running it on here will return an inaccurate result.**

https://jsfiddle.net/Pending/y7jmf8r5/show

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {

  let toolbarHInaccurate = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
  let toolbarH = e.screenY - e.clientY - window.screenY;
  
  console.log('Toolbar Height Innacurate:', toolbarHInaccurate + 'px');
  console.log('Toolbar Height Actual:', toolbarH + 'px');
  
})
```

```html
<button>Get Toolbar Height</button>
```

Measured, actual pixels: 114px
[image]

Result from toolbarH in code snippet: 114px
[image]

I'm using Windows 10 and `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` returned 120px which is inaccurate, but as stated by xyz, when he used that, it was accurate on his mac.

Comment: My result on mac running your fiddle: chrome Innacurate and Actual both 111px, firefox both 113px, safari both 52px

Comment: Interesting, thank you.